# How to specify a custom 404 view for Django using Class Based Views?

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

Using Django, you can override the default 404 page by doing this in the root `urls.py`:

```
handler404 = 'path.to.views.custom404'
```

How to do this when using Class based views? I can't figure it out and the documentation doesn't seem to say anything.

I've tried:

```
handler404 = 'path.to.view.Custom404.as_view'
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Never mind, I forgot to try this:

```
from path.to.view import Custom404
handler404 = Custom404.as_view()
```

Seems so simple now, it probably doesn't merit a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for us. I get `ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.`

Comment: @NicolasBouliane I have the same error. Did you manage to fix this ?

Comment: Simply call `.render()` on it.

Comment: I think simply overwriting the `dispatch` method and returning the response you want there is enough. You don't have to deal with `render` or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Managed to make it work by having the following code in my custom 404 CBV (found it on other StackOverflow post: [Django handler500 as a Class Based View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633508/django-handler500-as-a-class-based-view))

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class NotFoundView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "errors/404.html"

    @classmethod
    def get_rendered_view(cls):
        as_view_fn = cls.as_view()

        def view_fn(request):
            response = as_view_fn(request)
            # this is what was missing before
            response.render()
            return response

        return view_fn
```

In my root URLConf file I have the following:

```
from apps.errors.views.notfound import NotFoundView

handler404 = NotFoundView.get_rendered_view()
```

Comment: Careful, you should be returning a 404 status, not just displaying a template that looks like it. You should add `response.status_code = 404`.

Answer (score 1):

In your main `urls.py` you can just add `from app_name.views import Custom404`
and then set `handler404 = Custom404.as_view()`. 
It should work

Comment: This does seem to work as of 2021, Django 3.1.4. The workarounds in the other answers no longer appear to be required.