# django class based view custom 404 and 500

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to learn django, and I have a small test server (not devel) to this effect where I am trying to host a small blog site (similar to the official tutorial).

I'd like to have custom 404 and 500 views, so, I have the following in `urls.py`:

```
from mystuff.views import Template404View, Template500View
handler404 = Template404View.as_view()
handler500 = Template500View.as_view()
```

and in my `views.py`, I have the following:

```
class Template404View(TemplateView):
    template_name = "404.html"

class Template500View(TemplateView):
    template_name = "500.html"
```

where, the `404.html` and `500.html` are present in my `site_templates` directory.

However, when I host this on my test server, instead of seeing 400 or 500 custom pages, all I see is `Internal Server Error`.

I have tried to look up similar questions on SO, and I see the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149555/how-to-specify-a-custom-404-view-for-django-using-class-based-views), but this does not seem to help...

Any advice would be appreciated...Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem today: The problem was that I had German Umlauts in my 500-page and while rendering the 500-page, my apache had an internal server error and therefore raised an apache 200 error. So check your 500 page and test it seperately and see if it is displayed correctly when you call it.

But since you are following the tutorial: Why not taking the approach described in [Chapter 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/#write-a-404-page-not-found-view)? Just write your 500.html file and put it in my_app/templates. This works nicely, no additional views or urls are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing your custom views from mystuff while they are defined in views.py. try importing them from my stuff.views instead.

Also setting DEBUG=True could give you some clue

Comment: Sorry I made the `.views` typo - I have corrected this now. Havent tried DEBUG=True yet tho - but I guess this will just throw the default django 404 - which is not what I want.

Comment: If you are receiving an Internal Server Error (500) setting ´DEGUG=True`) will tell you more about the reason of the error. Probably the error is in some import or something like that before, therefore you can't server the correct 500.html.